# What is the operator &&?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The purpose of it is the operations within the overloaded method, but what would be it's true purpose?

```
class CModeType
{
public:
    CModeType(){m_nModeType=1;}
    ~CModeType(){}
    int m_nModeType;
    CModeType&              operator&&( const CModeType& rModeType );
};
CModeType& CModeType::operator &&( const CModeType& rModeType )
{
    this->m_nModeType += rModeType.m_nModeType;
    return *this;
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CModeType Mode;
    CModeType Mod2;
    Mode && Mode;
    cout << Mode.m_nModeType << endl; //output:2
    return 0;
}
```

I would also ask about  `||` but I believe the answer will help me to understand it so.

Comment: That's a very bad reason to overload `operator&&`. Be aware that overloading it causes short-circuiting not to occur any more.

Comment: lol, at first glance, I thought `Mode && Mode;` was an rvalue reference :)

Comment: Are you looking for the bitwise & ?

Comment: A well-asked question, nicely formatted and complete, but this is a fundamental concept of C++ covered in any beginning text.  If you are asking what `&&` means in C++, that is a question better answered by reading a good C++ text.  If your asking something else then that is not clear to me.  In either case, voted to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For built-in types, the `&&` operator is "logical-and", so that `x && y` is true if and only if both `x` and `y` are true when evaluated in a boolean context.

For built-in types, the `&&` operator is *short-circuited*, so that the second argument is never evaluated if the first one is already false, so you can say things like `if (p && *p == 10)` without risking a null-pointer dereferencing. For the overloaded `operator&&` of a user-defined type, this is not true, and it is just an ordinary function (so arguments are evaluated in an indeterminate order). Beware!

Comment: I feel like that can't possibly be what he's asking, since he's an experienced programmer. We must be misunderstanding the question...

Comment: @Aerovistae: Well, maybe, but the question is really "What is the operator &&", so if the OP was after something else, he should probably make that clearer.

Comment: Kerrek, can you show a small practical example of it? I got it, but I can't think of a way where it would be logically used.

Comment: @ViniyoShouta: Practical reasons for overloading the `operator&&` are very rare. Typical examples are when you're building your own mini-languages inside C++, like parsers or expression templates or such like. I think some of the arcane parts of Boost (Qi/Spirit/Phoenix/Lambda) use this fairly heavily; have a look. But you may well be confusing your users!

Comment: @ViniyoShouta: For example, Boost.Serialize uses `operator&` (single `&`) for the serialization action. Meh.

Answer (score 6):

> but what would be it's true purpose?

In this case, its purpose is to make code less readable and counter-intuitive.

In practice, there are few cases where you'd want to overload the **logical-AND operator** (this is the answer to the title of the question). This is not part of them.

Usually, `operator &&` should be marked as `const` because you don't expect it, nor should it, modify the objects. In this case, it's not, and it does. Would you really expect, logically, that after you do

```
a && b
```

`a` gets modified? **NO!** It's a gross abuse of the language.

Comment: If the downvote was because I initially wrote "it's" instead of "its", I fully deserve it.

Comment: Then how about `std::cout << x`, that shouldn't change `std::cout`, right? ;)

Comment: I think OP is looking for bitwise ops. the int+int in the && implementation.  Also gross abuse of the language would ge using a for(;cond;) for an if(cond) This is just poor form.

Comment: @FredOverflow sure it should. Not all operators are logically const.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I reserve the right to call any miss-used feature "abuse".

Comment: But `128 << 1` does not change anything either! How is it okay for streams to change that intuitive meaning of the `<<` operator?

Comment: @FredOverflow :)) you had that one up your sleeve from the start, didn't you? I'd respond that neither the stream nor bit-shift operators are intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

It means logical `and` -operator. In a code `if (a && b) { ... }` the `...` will be executed if both `a` and `b` are true.

In your code, you are overloading the operator, so you're giving it a whole new purpose defined in `CModeType& operator&&( const CModeType& rModeType )` implementation. It will sum m_nModeType of `this` and `rModeType` (parameter) and then return pointer to `this`. Seems pretty stupid and unlogical to me, I would recommend not to do so.